# Twig search with multiple parameters

Tags: php, twig

We are making a website with a search form. In that form users can search with text and checkboxes. With the checkboxes users can search only in the related categories.

We need to accomplish this with Craft CMS and Twig.

We tried the following method, but that didnt worked.

```
{% set query = craft.request.getParam('search-results') %}
      {% set nietBijdragePlichtig = craft.request.getParam('plg-Nee') %}
          {% if nietBijdragePlichtig == 'on' %}
              {% for entry in craft.entries.section('producten').limit(null).order(asc).search('query,     nietBijdragePlichtig').find() %}
<div id=”test”>test</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

and we tried:

```
    {% set query = craft.request.getParam('search-results') %}
     {% set nietBijdragePlichtig = craft.request.getParam('plg-Nee') %}
{% set alle = query ~ ' ' ~ nietBijdragePlichtig %}
         {% if nietBijdragePlichtig == 'on' %}
             {% for entry in     craft.entries.section(‘producten’).limit(null).order(asc).search(alle).find() %}
<div id=”test”>test</div>
{% endfor %}
{% endif %}
```

We also tried to use multiple     .search()

We tried both codes with different syntaxes.

How can we accomplish this?

Really thanks!

Comment: Move your code logic to the controller. If you aren't allowed to do this, then at least extend twig to seperate logic from view.

Comment: We are going to do that. The code we placed was just a test. If this is solve then we are going to do move the code.

Comment: Twig should be used to show information, not to query or modify it. Do this on the `PHP` side, it will save you a lot of trouble